# How do I use `lpr` to print multiple files using 4 pages per sheet?

Tags: printing, postscript, lpr

I create eps/png/pdf figures using python scripts.  I want to use one `lpr` command to print several figures with 4 on each sheet of paper.  The following command printed each figure on one fourth of a separate sheet.

```
lpr -o number-up=4 figure[0-9].eps
```

How can I get these to print 4 per page?

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to provide just a single file for lpr to print. If your files are encapsulated PostScript, perhaps all you need to do is concatenate them with an intervening `showpage` command:

```
  for f in figure[0-9]; do cat "$f"; echo 'showpage'; done |
  lpr -o number-up=4
```

Answer (score 2):

`psmerge` and `psnup` from [psutils](https://github.com/rrthomas/psutils) should do what you want.

```
psmerge figure[0-9].eps | psnup -4 | lpr
```

From the Description field in the Debian packaged version:

> Description-en: PostScript document handling utilities
>
> This collection of utilities is for manipulating PostScript documents.  Page selection and rearrangement are supported, including arrangement into signatures for booklet printing, and page merging for n-up printing.
>
> The following programs are included in psutils: epsffit, extractres, fixdlsrps, fixfmps, fixmacps, fixpsditps, fixpspps, fixscribeps, fixtpps, fixwfwps, fixwpps, fixwwps, getafm, includeres, psbook, psmerge, psnup, psresize, psselect, pstops, showchar

Comment: Maybe I need to set something up before using this.  The command printed a bunch of garbage text: `Unknown device: pswrite
%%BeginProcSet: PStoPS 1 15
userdict begin
[/showpage/erasepage/copypage]{dup where{pop dup load
 type/operatortype eq{ /PStoPSenablepage cvx 1 index load 1 array astore cvx {} bind /ifelse cvx 4 array astore cvx def}{pop}ifelse}{po
p}ifelse}forall /PStoPSenablepage true def
[/letter/legal/executivepage/a4/a4small/b5/com10envelope
 /monarchenvelope/c5envelope/dlenvelope/lettersmall/note
 /folio/quarto/a5]{dup where{dup wcheck{exch{}put}`....

Comment: can your python code produce plain postscript output instead of (or as well as) EPS?  if so, try it with that.  it shouldn't make a difference (eps is ps plus a thumbnail image), but it may.  if it can't try converting it to plain ps first.  BTW, rather than waste paper, redirect to a file and view in `gs` or something.