# How to print images two-sided using `lpr`?

Tags: printing, cups, images, lp

I have several photos, which I wish to print on a single piece of paper.  I have already tried:

- Using `convert` [to combine all images per side](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302954/printing-multiple-separate-pictures-on-one-physical-paper-page-with-terminal).  However, now I need to print them two-sided.
- Using `convert` to combine them into a single PDF for some reason results in each page being extra long, with the top half being blank, and the bottom half containing the image I need.  See [example of one such page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Q8xm.png) below.
- If these were EPS files rather than images, I could [combine them into a single file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/286670/how-do-i-use-lpr-to-print-multiple-files-using-4-pages-per-sheet) before printing them two-sided.  However, this is not an option for image files.
- Even combining them into a single TIF file [would not allow `lpr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338514/how-do-you-print-a-multipage-tiff-file-using-cups-lp-command) to print them two-sided.
- Naively sending them to `lpr` two files at a time, such as via

  ```
  lpr -o sides=two-sided-long-edge file1.tif file2.tif
  ```

  results in them being printed on two separate pages, since the system creates a separate `lpr` instance for each of the files.

Note: Conversion packages with a `2` in the middle, such as `img2pdf` and `tiff2ps`, are not available on my system.

[image: Top half blank]

Comment: I apologize if I wasn't clear.  In the last paragraph, I specify that I've tried precisely that; however, since they are two different files, they end up printing on two separate pages anyways.  I will now update that sentence to make it more clear.  As far as the agreement -- I needed to bring *some* example.  So I just chose what I had freely available (and wouldn't identify me).

Comment: @Theophrastus `pdftk` is available actually.  If that can lead to a solution, feel free to post it.

Comment: @Theophrastus If you saw the image included in the post  -- `convert` doesn't seem to correct the files correctly; instead, this huge white gap appears above the image.  I don't know if that's a bug with convert, or if there's something wrong with the program that created the images (since all images do this), or if there's some setting that needs to change.  But I currently don't know what else can convert these PNG's into PDF's.